# CodeIgniter Session and Flash Uploaders

Tags: php, flash, session, codeigniter, uploadify

I'm trying to solve the problem of session data getting lost when using any flash uploader (uploadify or SWFupload) with CodeIgniter.

I have tried by passing the session_id and start session using the old session_id, even then I can not get the data stored in session. Therefore I would like to request if you know any solution of this problem or can recommend me some session library to use instead of codeigniter session library, I will be thankful.

I read some forum post that this problem can be solved by using 'Native PHP Session' library, Can someone tell how can I use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about native sessions, but you might want to use the [SWFUpload cookies plugin](http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#plugins): this should force SWFUpload to send CodeIgniter's session cookie, and should hopefully solve your issue.

Let me know if that works.